# How to reset the index to 0 in an arraylist?

Tags: java

As per the flow..
I added 3 values to arraylist
then removed the value for the index 1

Then when I am trying to display all values using for loop, I am getting below error.
**Code** marked where the exception occurred
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY4Wc.png)

Below is the error message
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr2f5.png)

Comment: Without seeing the code for adding and deleting, we can not help you

Comment: Post the code and error as text not as image

Comment: Please review this SO question checklist and revise your question accordingly: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: @JoeC I did'n know that Jon Skeet has a checklist for SO. Thanks.

Comment: 1st, as previously asked here, place your code here and not by image. 2nd, from the image you sent it is unclear where does the iterator is created.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentModificationException sounds like you are trying to modify the Collection from another thread while this thread iterates over it. That's not allowed.